# How to overload the operator<< from within a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

This is the smallest contained example I can think of.
First the header of the class. This class should simply print the one double it contains whenever the << operator is used.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef EURO_H
#define EURO_H

#include <ostream>

namespace EU
{
   class Euro final
   {
   public:
        explicit Euro(double value);
        virtual ~Euro() = default;

        double getValue() const;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Euro &euro);

    private:
        double m_value;
    };
}

#endif // EURO_H
```

Now the .cpp

```
#include "euro.h"

using namespace EU;

Euro::Euro(double value)
{
    m_value = value;
}

double Euro::getValue() const
{
    return m_value;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Euro &euro)
{
    os << euro.getValue() << "EUR";
    return os;
}
```

And finally, the main.cpp

```
#include "euro.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace EU;

int main()
{
    auto e = Euro(3.14);
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

However, when I compile this using:

```
g++ -std=c++11 *.cpp
```

it spits out the following error:

```
/tmp/ccP7OKC5.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `EU::operator<<(std::ostream&, EU::Euro const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,
Joris

Comment: You could strip it down further by not having `value` at all and just [attempting to] print a static value!

Comment: As a tip you do not need both `#pragma once` and header guards `#ifndef ... #define .... #endif`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're expecting `using namespace EU;` to put all the subsequent code inside `namespace EU`, but it won't (otherwise your `int main` would be in the namespace too!). This just brings things already in that namespace into scope.

It means that you're declaring the friend function inside the namespace, but defining a *new* function in the global scope. Calls to the former will fail because there's no definition for it.

Remove the `using namespace`, and wrap `namespace EU { }` around everything in `euro.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your cpp file from this:

```
#include "euro.h"

using namespace EU;

Euro::Euro(double value)
{
    m_value = value;
}

double Euro::getValue() const
{
    return m_value;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Euro &euro)
{
    os << euro.getValue() << "EUR";
    return os;
}
```

to this:

```
#include "euro.h"

namespace EU {  

Euro::Euro(double value)
{
    m_value = value;
}

double Euro::getValue() const
{
    return m_value;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Euro &euro)
{
    os << euro.getValue() << "EUR";
    return os;
}

} // namespace EU
```

This defines the code within this cpp file to be within the namespace. What you was previously doing was declaring your namespace to be used at the global scope of that file as you were not defining your source code to be within the namespace.